# Доступ к контенту со временем

Tags: android

Добрый день! Мне необходимо сделать так, что-бы контент в приложении открывался постепенно.
Например: В приложении 60 изображений, в первую неделю пользователь видит 20, во вторую у него появляется ещё 20 и т.д. 
Буду премного благодарен, если подскажете в какую сторону копать.

Comment: Думаю рациональнее всего действовать так: клиент получает уникальный `id`, создаётся сессия сохраняется в бд на сервере, туда пишется время в unix формате старта отсчёта, на сервере создаётся планировщик задач, который допустим каждый час пробегается по базе ищет подходящее время. Приложение при запуске делает запрос на сервер, либо создаёте `service` который будет мониторить в фоне ситуацию. Ну ещё структура зависит от планируемой нагрузки, сколько клиентов? Если хотите делать офлайн, то его вскроют скорее всего просто

Comment: Я думаю целевая аудитория не вскроет, а если вскроет, то и ладно. Приложение - детские раскраски =) Хотелось бы конечно как-то оффлайн сделать

Comment: Ну тогда все тоже самое только храним данные у клиента) просто при запуске проверяем время текущее и время точки отсчёта и на основании результата действуем)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пользователь скачивает приложение со всеми картинками. В [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)  сохраняете дату первого запуска приложения. При открытии активити со списком раскрасок делаете сверку сохраненной даты с текущей банальными

```
if (текущая дата-7дней >дата запуска) {
  запуск списка с показом изначального  картинок +20;
}else{
  запуск первичного списка;
}
```

И так далее насколько нужно растянуть показ картинок.